# Posting with parameter and returning as a json response

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest, http, post

**How do I post data to web api and return a result?**

I'm trying to pass in data to web api, and returning a result set in the form of json.

```
    <div class="panel1" ng-show="tab===2">
    <table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped" ng-controller="GetSamplesByStatus">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SampleId</th>
                <th>Barcode</th>
                <th>CreatedAt</th>
                <th>CreatedBy</th>
                <th>StatusId</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in dataset | limitTo:10">
                <td>{{row.Sample.SampleId}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Sample.Barcode}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Sample.CreatedAt | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Sample.CreatedBy}}</td>
                <td>{{row.Sample.StatusId}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('GetAllSamplesByStatusUser',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:36059/api/Samples/GetAllSamplesByStatusUser')
            .then(function (data) {
                $scope.dataset = data.data;
            });
    });

app.controller('GetSamplesByStatus',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $http.post("http://localhost:36059/api/Samples/GetSamplesByStatus" + '?statustype=Received') //"received' for now it is just a placeholder, this would be the parameter which I am passing in
            .then(function(data) {
                $scope.dataset = data.data;
            });
    });
```

When navigating to the URL: http://localhost:36059/api/Samples/GetSamplesByStatus?statustype=Received I am getting the following json result:

[image]

Finally, in my web api, my response is:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetSamplesByStatus(string statustype)
{
    var result = from sample in Samples
                 join status in Statuses
                     on sample.StatusId equals status.StatusId
                 where status.StatusType == statustype
                 select sample;

    return Json(result);
}
```

When running my POSTer, I get an empty dataset:

[image]

I am getting this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405
>   (Method Not Allowed)

After researching the issue, I've installed on chrome.

[image]

This is working when I do simply GETs, but for the issue at hand it is not making a difference.

**How do I post data to web api and return a result?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify the Content-Type of your post data in the header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

For example:

```
var serializedData = $.param({name: "myname", age:24});

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: (ENDPOINT URL),
        data: serializedData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }}).then(function(response) {
               console.log(response);
           }, function(error) {
               console.log(error);
           });
```

Comment: sorry im a beginner with the front end but your solution looks like jquery, not angular

Comment: You truly are hahaha. Read all about it https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: You have to enable CORS in your WebAPI Solution. Check here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api or http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html

Comment: Can you take out the `$scope.dataset = response;` and just log the data first `console.log(response)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115944/discussion-between-oluwafemi-and-l).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115946/discussion-between-l-and-oluwafemi).

Comment: let me know when you are available